# Regex to exclude word (XML Schema flavor)

Tags: regex, xsd

currently I'm trying to find a regular expression with the following condition:

```
Match:          FOO_.* (valid if the string contains FOO_ at the beginning)
Don't Match:    FOO_BAR (not valid if the string contains BAR)
```

Usually I would use the following expression:

```
FOO_(?!BAR)
```

My problem with that solution is, that I want to use it in a xml schema. Using it with a parsers brings up the following error message:

```
schema.xsd:50: element pattern: Schemas parser error : Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}pattern': The value 'FOO_(?!BAR)' of the facet 'pattern' is not a valid regular expression.
WXS schema schema.xsd failed to compile
```

Is there a readable ;-) working solution or is it just not possible inside a xml schema?

Comment: Possible duplicate of:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812790/restrict-word-list-in-xml-schema

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restrict word list in XML schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812790/restrict-word-list-in-xml-schema)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) part `(?!BAR)` of your expression is not supported in XML schema.

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html
- http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#regexs

For your specific example the following expression should give you an idea how you could workaround this limitation:

```
FOO_([^B].*|B([^A].*|A([^R].*)?)?)?
```

Comment: What about `FOO_` or am I missing something

Comment: @WordsLikeJared Hey this should rather just give the idea! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Will the following technique not work for the phrase you're trying to exclude?

[Restrict word list in XML schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812790/restrict-word-list-in-xml-schema)