# Blacklist words in XML

Tags: xml, regex, blacklist

My requirement is : 
"*Dont allow blacklisted words to appear in a specific XML tag*".

I am trying with xs:restriction using XML regex pattern.

I referenced the following link : [Restrict word list in XML schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812790/restrict-word-list-in-xml-schema).

eg: BLACKLISTED WORDS : **byte,bing,ding**

The problem : If the words start with the same letter (**b**), ***byte*** passes for ***bing*** condition and *vice versa*.

Is there an AND operator I can use ? Is there any other simpler way ?

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Michael Kay's answer, I have implemented the logic using XSD 1.1.
(I had to change *$value* to *@name*)

Steps:
1. Used the following code with latest Xerces 1.1 implementation jar files.

```
<xs:element name="random-element">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="name" use="required" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:attribute name="value" use="optional" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:assert test="not(tokenize(@name, '\s+') = ('byte', 'bing', 'ding'))"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

3. Validated using the following code :

```
 final SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(Constants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA11_NS_URI);
 final Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaFile);
 final Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
 validator.validate(xmlFile);
```

The constant **W3C_XML_SCHEMA11_NS_URI** is very important, else it will *fail*.

Comment: What package is `Constants` in?

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you did, you got it wrong; and we can't really work out what you did by reading that long thread that you referenced, so you'll have to tell us. It might also be a good idea to tell us what you are trying to achieve, because there might be a better way. Apart from anything else, the world has moved on since 2009, and you might be able to use XSD 1.1.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for the info! I have updated the question. I hope its more clear now. Is there a better way to restrict words in XSD 1.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

In the original question it was relatively straightforward, translating each forbidden *word* to a list of allowed *patterns*.  But in this case the resulting lists would conflict, so you have to consider all the words at once as you generate a comprehensive list of patterns:

- Starts with anything but `b` or `d`
- Starts with `b`, next character not `y` or `i`
- Starts with `by`, next character not `t`
- Starts with `byt`, next character not `e`
- Starts with `byte` AND has at least one more character
- `byt`, `by` or `b`
- Starts with `d`, next character not `i`
- Starts with `bi` or `di`, next character not `n`
- Starts with `bin` or `din`, next character not `g`
- Starts with `bing` or `ding` AND has at least one more character
- `bin`, `bi`, `b`, `din`, `di` or `d`

result:

```
<xsd:pattern value=
  "([^bd].*|b[^yi].*|by[^t].*|byt[^e].*|byte.+|b(yt?)?|d[^i].*|[bd]i[^n].*|[bd]in[^g].*|[bd]ing.+|[bd](in?)?)"
/>
```

It might be possible to write a program to generate the regex, but that looks like a helluva lot of work.  I haven't looked at this problem since I wrote my answer to the original question; I would hope, as @MichaelKay says, that a better solution has come along in the meantime.

Comment: Hi Alan, Thanks for your suggestion. Actually I had written a program to generate your previous regex. But then I suddenly realized it goes wrong with the same starting letter. I will try to write a program if I cant do it in XSD1.1. But thanks anyway !

Comment: No problem.  Don't forget to update this Q/A when you've got your solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help Alan. I have updated my question with my implementation.

Comment: How about repeating the pattern? XSD simply tests all the patterns; if content doesn't match *all* of them it fails. So you just ask for (NOT X) AND (NOT Y) AND...

Answer (score 0):

In XSD 1.1 you can do this:

```
<xs:assert test="not(tokenize($value, '\s+') = ('byte', 'bing', 'ding'))"/>
```

XSD 1.1 is currently supported in Saxon and Xerces.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael ! I tried downloading the latest Xerces jar and tried parsing the xml, but somehow it doesn't detect any XSD 1.1 syntax.

Comment: Also if i decompile XMLScanner.class in jre/rt.jar and xerces, the method versionSupported() checks for both 1.0 and 1.1 in jre/rt.jar, BUT in xerces.jar its checking only for 1.0.

Comment: Information on Xerces support for XSD 1.1 can be found here: http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-xs.html - however, I can't help you further as I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Thanks for your help Michael. The 1.1 support was in the beta version Xerces jar which i missed. Also I had to change $value to @name to make my code work. I have updated the question with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

XSD 1.1 is probably the way to go if possible. The other answers have already covered this and I tend to trust them :-)

In XSD 1.0 the only way to stack negations is to repeat the restriction condition (`xs:pattern`)using negated sets, one per (positive) assertion, e.g.:

```
<xs:pattern value="([^(byte)]" />
<xs:pattern value="([^(bing)])" />
<xs:pattern value="([^(ding)])" />
```

You could also further specify capitalization per word, per letter etc.

As long as you negate the whole thing you are "blacklisting" you should be able to build it up out of relatively readable patterns.